# Retrofit Service not getting called/working and has no error either Android Retrofit, Kotlin, Viewmodel

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm currently working on an Android app where I'm trying to make an API call using Retrofit and display the retrieved data in a RecyclerView. Below, I've included relevant code snippets for the Retrofit setup, ViewModel, and related components.

1. Retrofit Instance and Service:
   I've defined the Retrofit instance and service for making API calls as follows:

```java
interface ApiServices {
    @GET("home/banners.php")
    suspend fun getBannersList(): Response<ResponseBanner>
}
```

2. ResponseBanner Class:
   The ResponseBanner class is defined as an extension of ArrayList to hold the API response data:

```java
class ResponseBanner : ArrayList<ResponseBanner.ResponseBannerItem>() {
    data class ResponseBannerItem(
        @SerializedName("id")
        val id: Int?,
        @SerializedName("image")
        val image: String?,
        @SerializedName("link")
        val link: String?,
        @SerializedName("type")
        val type: String?
    )
}
```

3. HomeRepository Class:
   The repository class for fetching data from the API is defined as follows:

```java
class HomeRepository @Inject constructor(private val api: ApiServices) {
    suspend fun getBannerList() = api.getBannersList()
}
```

4. MVI State and Intent Classes

Here are the HomeIntent and HomeState sealed classes:

```java
sealed class HomeIntent {
    data class LoadBanners(val banner: MutableList<ResponseBanner.ResponseBannerItem>) : HomeIntent()
}

sealed class HomeState {
    object Idle : HomeState()
    object LoadingProfile : HomeState()
    object LoadingBanner : HomeState()
    object Empty : HomeState()
    data class BannerListItem(val banner: MutableList<ResponseBanner.ResponseBannerItem>) : HomeState()
    data class Error(val error: String) : HomeState()
}
```

5.HomeViewModel Class:
The ViewModel responsible for managing UI state and interacting with the repository is defined as follows:

```java
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: HomeRepository) : ViewModel() {
    val intentChannel = Channel<HomeIntent>()
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow<HomeState>(HomeState.Idle)
    val state: StateFlow<HomeState> get() = _state

    init {
        handleIntents()
    }

    private fun handleIntents() = viewModelScope.launch {
        intentChannel.consumeAsFlow().collect { intent ->
            when (intent) {
                is HomeIntent.LoadBanners -> fetchingBanner()
            }
        }
    }


    private suspend fun fetchingBanner() {
        val response = repository.getBannerList()
        when (response.code()) {
            in 200..202 -> {
                _state.emit(HomeState.BannerListItem(response.body()!!))
            }

            in 400..499 -> {
                _state.emit(HomeState.Error(""))
            }

            in 500..599 -> {
                _state.emit(HomeState.Error(""))
            }
        }
    }

}
```

6. HomeFragment Class:
   Here's a snippet of the HomeFragment class where I'm observing the ViewModel's state to update the UI:

```java
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    //Binding
    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    @Inject
    lateinit var bannerAdapter: AdapterBanner


    //other
    private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModels()
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //initViews
        binding.apply {
            //lifecycle
            viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
                viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                    viewModel.state.collect { state ->
                        when (state) {
                            is HomeState.Idle -> {}
                            is HomeState.LoadingBanner -> {}
                            is HomeState.LoadingProfile -> {}
                            is HomeState.BannerListItem -> {}
                            is HomeState.Empty -> {}
                            is HomeState.Error -> {}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

I've also added the necessary Internet access permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and included `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`.

Despite setting up the code as shown above, I've encountered an issue where the API call doesn't seem to be made when I use breakpoints inside the ViewModel. I've checked for errors and reviewed the code, but I can't figure out why the call isn't being made. Can someone please help me identify what might be causing this issue?
'I use the latest version of Retrofit and Okhttp'
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I tested using a breakpoint , the view model is not called at all, the function I used to call the banner.

Comment: can you a json sample of your response json

Comment: Well, what I do see is that your error state destroys your previously loaded data, which always causes issues.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: did you pass HomeIntent.LoadBanners event to intentChannel ?

Answer (score 0):

You never sent an intent to load the banners,

In the ViewModel you need to do the following

```
init{
     handleIntents()
     onIntent(HomeIntent.LoadBanners)/*I don't know your business requirement,
 you may choose to call this from fragment on a button click or from a lifecycle callback.*/
}


fun onIntent(intent:HomeIntent) = viewModelScope.launch {
    intentChannel.send(intent)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Your answer is not correct because here
`init
     onIntent(HomeIntent.LoadBanners)
}`
It needs to be initialized and `handleIntents()`
What I wrote also does the same thing

Comment: I think you need to look in the control flow and how the flow works, to collect something you need to send something, you are converting a channel to a flow and collecting, but you never sent a value in the channel, **that is what I am trying to explain in the answer**

Comment: In your fragment code as well, I don't see a call like ```viewModel.intentChannel.send(HomeIntent.LoadBanners)```

Comment: I suggest you go through this article for better understanding of how MVI works and essentially what MVI is, https://medium.com/swlh/mvi-architecture-with-android-fcde123e3c4a